# Is there a way to replace global variables conditionaly in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I have discovered the "prefers-color-scheme" media query recently and saw that newer versions of most common browsers are compatible with it.

I wanted to make some SCSS code that generates global variables to export with the value depending on the "prefers-color-scheme" in order to avoid duplicating "theme classes".

```
$schemeColor: #eeeeee !default;
$reverseColor: #333333 !default;
$textColor: #000000 !default;


@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark){
  $schemeColor: #333333 !global;
  $reverseColor: #eeeeee !global;
  $textColor: #FFFFFF !global;
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    $schemeColor: #eeeeee !global;
    $reverseColor: #333333 !global;
    $textColor: #000000 !global;
}
```

When I use one of the variables after this piece of code, whatever is the prefers-color scheme, the values stored in variables will be the last that are written

(here: the values that are set in `@media (prefers-color-scheme: light)`).

I have tried to create classes inside the media queries.
When I do this, the classes declared inside the media-queries are correctly applied depending on color-scheme, but the variables keep storing the last value that they had been set to.

Comment: Have you tried `$schemeColor: #333333;` instead of `$schemeColor: #333333 !global;`?

Comment: @Morpheus, Yes, but when i do, the variable come back to the global-scope-value when the media query is closed, and then it is not exportable with the wanted value.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. SCSS variables get replaced when you build your CSS. So `color: $textColor` in SCSS will be `color: #000000` in your generated CSS file. It would be possible with CSS variables, but these are not supported everywhere yet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, this cannot be done by the simple fact that SCSS is a pre-processor and as such, the code you generate in SCSS will be converted to CSS and all the variables you use, will be transformed in the values.

If you want variables and change them by rules, you should use CSS variables, like this:

```
:root {
  --main-bg-color: coral; 
}

 @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark){
 :root {
  --main-bg-color: red; 
}
}

.element{
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it looks like SCSS reads and locks all variables without taking in consideration the media queries that are CSS. And so CSS variables seems to be a better way to do what I want to. Thanks :)

Comment: The proper way to do what I wanted to with SCSS would be to use `@mixin` containing the media query and that is exportable.  
Since the results of media queries are cached, having tons of media queries should not lead to performance issue. 
[This page](https://css-tricks.com/conditional-media-query-mixins/) inspired me to find this solution

Comment: Oh yeah, I've been using something like this in my personal project, didn't mension because I thought that you only wanted to use real SCSS variables. Anyway, I encourage to use @mixins , it's a pretty clean approach.

Comment: So, I am struggling with the exact same thing. Can't get my mind around the mixin in SCSS, is it possible to do what was originally asked in SCSS with the mixin command? @KevinSubrebost ?

Comment: @PedroFigueiredo with mixins your'e giving up on function like 'darken', 'lighten' and so on.., sad that there is not a real clean approach :\